# How to compile Linux socket programs on windows?

Tags: sockets

I've done these simple programs like half duplex communication using pipes, full duplex communication using pipes and some of simple socket programs on Red Hat Linux using the Text Editor and Terminal. The 2 commands i used were ./gcc and ./out something like that.

Problem is, i did that in my university. They have Linux installed on their PC's. But i don't have it on my PC. So i need to practice those programs(without changing anything in the code) on my Windows 7(64-bit) PC.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use cygwin http://www.cygwin.com/ it's very old but it's still working. Good luck.

Comment: i guess its a really long procedure. I just got 2 or 3 hours. Anything else?

Comment: well 2 o 3 hours it's not a long procedure, in the enterprise world, some projects can take 2 or 3 weeks, another way it's using gcc, but it'll take more than a few hours ;)